# Deduce the sum of the rows of $\mathbf{XX}^T$ from $\mathbf{X}$

Tags: matrices

Given an arbitrary matrix $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, is it possible to deduce the sum of the rows of matrix $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top$ efficiently i.e. without having to explicitly compute $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can decrease the complexity to O($mn$) if you're looking to write a program(as compared to O($m^2n$), if you multiply directly). Your problem is equivalent to computing $XX^T\textbf{1}$ ($\textbf{1}$ is a vector of ones). Do it in the following order:

$X^T\textbf{1}$ is O(mn), and it gives an nx1 vector V. XV is again O(mn) making the entire thing O(mn).